# Img alt on mobile screen

Tags: html, css

I have got some pictures on my site as a summary, so when the user hovers the image, it shows the alt message as normal.

When it cames to a touch screen, if I tap over the image it doesn't show anything and the user can`t know what the image means.

How could i work around to show a text when the user taps over the image on a touch screen?

Answer (score 1):

The mobile screen (precisely on touchscreen device) not support `hover` action. And `hover` action will works if you long touch on your device.

Read this [article](http://www.prowebdesign.ro/how-to-deal-with-hover-on-touch-screen-devices/) for better comprehension.